# usage: but now to V

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I'd like to know whether and how "but now to V" is correctly used in the following.

> In your example, the context would have to be that the other person has been interrupting you by constantly saying that you never really loved her, you only thought you did. You may have tried to argue about this, **but now** - because you ｗant to finish the story - **to** reluctantly and grudgingly say that you will allow "or thought you did" to be inserted into your story.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "but now to V" makes me think about a context where there was a previous situation, action for the purpose of achieving something, then (**but now** ...) the same situation/action has a different purpose, a different target or objective (" ... **to do** something").

That is exactly what it's expressed in your quote:

1. Previous situation: You were arguing with her with the intent of denying what she was saying (that you've never loved her).
2. Current situation: Now you are arguing with the intent of finishing your story.